# passing a html select value to a JS object

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have a regular HTML form with some inputs and 1 select value that i am passing to a JS object..

I don't know how to grab the value of the selected option.

```
var dataObj = {
firstName: $("input[name='firstName']", _form).val(),
lastName: $("input[name='lastName']", _form).val(),
lastName2: $("input[name='lastName2']", _form).val(),
email: $("input[name='email']", _form).val(),
oldPassword: $("input[name='oldPassword']", _form).val(),
newPassword: $("input[name='newPassword']", _form).val(),
userType: $("select[name=usertype]", _form).val(),};
```

I am grabbing al the values of the inputs fine, but the value of the select menu comes undefine... any help for a noob?

```
          <select class="uk-select" name="usertype" id="userType">
              <option value="0" <?php if ($UserEdit ->userType == 0) {echo "selected";} ?> >Needs Auth</option>
              <option value="1" <?php if ($UserEdit ->userType == 1) {echo "selected";} ?> >Super Admin</option>
              <option value="2" <?php if ($UserEdit ->userType == 2) {echo "selected";} ?> >Supervisor</option>
              <option value="3" <?php if ($UserEdit ->userType == 3) {echo "selected";} ?> >Operator</option>
              <option value="4" <?php if ($UserEdit ->userType == 4) {echo "selected";} ?> >Hotel Admin</option>
              <option value="5" <?php if ($UserEdit ->userType == 5) {echo "selected";} ?> >Guest</option>
              <option value="6" <?php if ($UserEdit ->userType == 6) {echo "selected";} ?> >Visitor</option>
          </select>
```

Comment: misspelled selector? `selec[name=usertype]`, you're missing the `t` in select.

Comment: I missspelled it here, not in the code. Apologies.

Comment: `$("select[name=usertype]"` another typo -> add the quotes around usertype `$("select[name='usertype']"`

Comment: @ChrisLuna you may also want to show the code of your html form.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.  You wanna use the `:selected` psuedo selector:

```
userType: $("select[name='usertype'] option:selected").val()
// or it could be .text()
userType: $("select[name='usertype'] option:selected").text()

//without the attribute select - give it an id
userType: $("#userType option:selected").text()
```

`Learn jQuery` has a great page on exactly what you're doing:

[Learn jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/)

Comment: let me know if this works or throws an exception.  I've never tried it with attribute selectors

Comment: `userType: $("select[name='usertype'] option:selected", _form).val()` and `userType: $("input[name='usertype'] option:selected", _form).val()` Both are giving me the userType as undefined

Comment: wait a sec, I maybe misunderstood.  are all the `inputs` working fine?  it's only the `select` that's giving you issue?

Comment: that is correct only the `select` comes up as undefined

Comment: updated to reflect the select.  If none of those are working, can we see your markup for the select?

Comment: BTW $('select-selector').val() should work perfectly fine.No need to get to the option:selected and using .text() would select the text of the option not its value. If you wanted the value by selecting the option you would need to use .attr('value');

Comment: Yip, that's why I wanted to see the markup.  What's `$('select-selector')`?  I get the `select`, but what's the `-selector` part  referring to?  But OP - `jquery .val()` will totally get you the value prop unless you don't have a value prop, then I think it get the `<option>` text

Comment: I tried both with .text() and useing the ID to grab the value, and adding the ID to the Select Tag... I updated my original post with the Select HTML code. Still undefined

Comment: @ChrisLuna Try removing the _form context if anything changes?

Comment: @DMcCallum83 select-selector was just a placeholder for any selector.

Answer (score 0):

I put an id# on the `select` tag and used this `userType: $("#userType option:selected", _form).attr('value'),` in my javascript to grab the value. It worked like a charm. The main issues is that I was trying to grab the value of `select`, which technically it doesn't have. So I needed to grab the attribute value of the selected `option`.